# If data is square rooted to assume normality, should the data used to test with Levene's Test for Equality of Variance also be square rooted?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, python, data-transformation, manova

I am going to run a MANOVA, two of the assumptions are normally distributed data and equal variances.

I had a data set that non-normally distributed. I square rooted it, and it is approximately normally distributed now. The data set is 155 data points/rows long.

Considering I square rooted data for normality testing, should I keep the data in square root format to test for Equality of Variance (Levene's Test), or revert back to the raw data?

Answer (score 2):

If you do the equality of variance test for the purposes of assumptions of manova, you need to test the data on the scale you will use in the manova.

Presumably (after what you told us) that is the square root scale.